# Grid Search better performance using threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a classification problem and I have implemented a grid search algorithm in order to find the best accuracy. My problem is that the program's execution time is about 2 hours and I have tried to improve this time by using threads. Obviously something I'm doing wrong since the execution time was the same even after implementing the threads. Bellow is the algorithm.

I must specify that is the first time I am using threads, I have read some good things about Executors, but I can't figure out how to implement them.

```
public static void gridSearch(Dataset ds)
        {
            double bestAcc = 0;

            for (int i = -5; i < 15; i++) {
                double param1 = Math.pow(2, i);
                for (int j = -15; j < 3; j++) {
                    double param2 = Math.pow(2, j);

                    int size = 10;
                    CrossValidation[] works = new CrossValidation[size];
                    Thread[] threads = new Thread[size];
                    for (int k=1;k<=size;k++) {
                        CrossValidation po = new CrossValidation(param1, param2, ds);;
                        works[k-1] = po;
                        Thread t = new Thread(po);
                        threads[k-1] = t;
                        t.start();
                    }
                    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                        try { threads[k].join(); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
                        double accuracy = works[k].getAccuracy();
                        accuracy /= 106;
                        if (accuracy > bestAccuracy)
                            bestAcc = accuracy;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Best accuracy: " + bestAcc);
        }
```

The `CrossValidation` class implements `Runnable` and has a method `getAccuracy` that returns the accuracy.

Please help me figure it out what I am doing wrong, in order to improve the execution time.

Comment: How many CPU's does you're machine have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you start for each parameter setting 10 threads instead of starting a thread for each parameter setting. Look closely what you're doing here. You're generating `param1` and `param2` and then start 10 threads that work with those parameters - redundantly. After that you are waiting for those threads to finish before you start over again.

But no worries, I have prepared something for you ...

---

I want to show you how you could make a Thread Pool do what you actually want to achieve here. It will be easier to understand once you get it running and note that:

**You can download the whole example [here](http://codepad.org/W7QI1Q6b)**.

First you need a `WorkerThread` and something like `CVResult` to return the results. This is where you are going to perform the CrossValidation algorithm:

```
public static class CVResult {      
    public double param1;
    public double param2;
    public double accuracy;
}

public static class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private double param1;
    private double param2;
    private double accuracy;

    public WorkerThread(double param1, double param2){   
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                " [parameter1] " + param1 + " [parameter2]: " + param2);
        processCommand();
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(500);
            ;
            /*
             * ### PERFORM YOUR CROSSVALIDATION ALGORITHM HERE ###
             */

            this.accuracy = this.param1 + this.param2;

            // Give back result:

            CVResult result = new CVResult();

            result.accuracy = this.accuracy;
            result.param1 = this.param1;
            result.param2 = this.param2;

            Main.addResult(result);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to assure you have access to a `ExecutorService` and `List<Future>`. `ExecutorService` will take care of your threads and we will initialize the number of threads to be the number of cores that your CPU has available. *This will ensure that no more threads are running than cores are available on your CPU - however - no task gets lost because each thread gets **enqueued** and starts after another has finished*.  You'll see that soon. `List<Future>` will allow us to wait for all threads to finish before we continue with the main thread. `List<CVResult>` is of course there to hold the results added by the threads (*note that it is synchronized since multiple threads are going to access it*).

```
private static ExecutorService executor = null;
private static List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
private static List<CVResult> resultList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<CVResult>());
```

This is how your `gridSearch()` would look like. You don't have to initialize `executor` here.. you can do that wherever you want of course:

```
public static void gridSearch(/*Dataset ds*/)
{
    double bestAcc = 0;

    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);

    for (int i = -5; i < 15; i++) {

        double param1 = Math.pow(2, i);

        for (int j = -15; j < 3; j++) { 

            double param2 = Math.pow(2, j);  

            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(param1, param2);
            futures.add(executor.submit(worker));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Waiting for all threads to terminate ..");

    // Joining all threads in order to wait for all to finish
    // before returning from gridSearch()
    for (Future future: futures) {
        try {
            future.get(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            // process cause
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Printing results ..");

    for(CVResult result : resultList) {
        System.out.println("Acc: " + result.accuracy + 
                " for param1: " + result.param1 + 
                " | param2: " + result.param2);
    }
}
```

Last but not least here is a synchronized method to add your results to the list:

```
public static void addResult(CVResult accuracy) {
    synchronized( resultList ) {
        resultList.add(accuracy);
    }       
}
```

If you call this in your main e.g. like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    gridSearch(/* params */);       
    System.out.println("All done.");
}
```

You'll get an output like this:

```
...
pool-1-thread-5 [parameter1] 0.0625 [parameter2]: 3.0517578125E-5
param1 0.03125
param2 1.0
pool-1-thread-4 [parameter1] 0.0625 [parameter2]: 0.25
param1 0.0625
param2 0.03125
...
Printing results ..
...
Acc: 16384.5 for param1: 16384.0 | param2: 0.5
Acc: 16386.0 for param1: 16384.0 | param2: 2.0
...
All done.
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer! It is very clearly. However I have some question. As I posted in the question, each worker should return an accuracy, I have already done that in `WorkerThread` like `public double getAccuracy()` but I don't know where to retrieve it in the `grisSearch`.  Can you help me?

Comment: @GeR I have updated my answer and also the example you can download above. There are a few ways to return something from threads. One way is to create a result-object that you put into a `List`, `Map`, `Set` or whatever you like. Note that this container has to be somehow synchronized or else you'll get in trouble with your threads (I've done that for you in the example). There might me ways that are more elegant but I think that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because thread creation/teardown overhead is increasing the time needed to run the threads, fix this by using Executors. [This will help you get started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html). As commented already, your processor may also not have the available processing threads or physical cores to execute your threads concurrently.

More prominently, between each of the -15 to 3 iterations, you must wait. To fix this, move your waiting and processing to the end of the for loop, once everything is processed. That way, the last 10 threads do not need to completely before starting the next batch. Additionally, I recommend using a `CountDownLatch` to await full completion before processing the results.